# Terminal freezes on running apt-get or vim

Tags: apt, ssh, vim, amazon-ec2

I am using *Ubuntu 13.04* on my laptop.

I `ssh` to my *EC2 instance* which is running *Ubuntu 12.04.3* and every time I run `sudo apt-get update`, it prints some lines and then the terminal freezes.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release                                 
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources

(no further output)
```

Similarly it freezes with a blank screen when open a file (or new file) in `vim`, while `nano` works perfectly fine.

I would also like to point out that this wasn't happening a day back and before this issue cropped up I ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` on ec2 instance which worked fine as usual.

This has made my AWS instance unusable which is where I do most of my work. Any ideas as to what might be causing this and what might fix it?

I have tried re-installing `vim` (which works by the way) but it still freezes, I feel helpless, please help me.

**Note:** Interestingly, I can still edit files in `vim`, I just can't see anything happening on the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the MTU value on ec2 solved it for me...

```
sudo /sbin/ifconfig eth0 mtu 1492
```

Comment: U are the best! 1000 working value for me. Thnks.